# How to upload the documents in the document path to iPad

Tags: iphone, ipad

It is the first time that I have tested my app on an iPad outside of the simulator. I have some files whose path is retrieved using:

```
  NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
  NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
```

When running in the simulator everything is ok, but on the iPad it seems that the files in the document directory are not uploaded. How can I upload all of these files to the iPad?

Comment: What's **put up all these files** mean? I don't understand your question. Can you try explaining a little clearer.

Comment: I mean "upload", can you understand now?

Comment: **Upload** them where? Do you mean **ADD** Files to the Documents directory? Where are the files located?

Comment: Try saving those files in Resource folder.

Comment: It is in the "Document" on mac. But when I test on ipad, there is no file in the "Document" on ipad

Answer (score 1, accepted):

iOS devices follow sandbox environment, so every app have its own Documents folder.
To save files in the documents folder, you can try the following:

```
 //This will provide you path for the document folder of your app.
 NSString *documentsPath = [NSHomeDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Documents"];
```

Now, you can use this path to append path of your files and save your files.
Please let me know if any query.

Comment: your solution is not what I want. But your explaination inspired me, Thanks!

Comment: Can you please tell me, where are your files residing in iPad app?